# Comparison between displacement of a ball under pure rolling and slipping

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

In which of the following cases of the orientation of the blades of grass will a ball travel the furthest before stopping, considering that the blades of grass in case 2 provide sufficient friction to the ball for pure rolling. (Keep in mind that the ball is put in motion from the left-hand side)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the first scenario would let a ball travel the furthest before stopping. This is because the blades of grass are pointing *towards* the ball in the second scenario. This would mean that there is increased resistance in that scenario. The blades of grass are almost stopping the ball from rolling; it's only because the blades are flexible that the ball can move at all.